# Spring 4: @async nativeQuery running before the calling @transactional transaction commits

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a `@transactional` method in a Spring web `@Controller` that calls an `@async` method. The `@transactional` method persists an entity to the Spring-wired  `javax.persistence.entitymanager` and calls an `@async` function to save some derivative data to an analytics server. The `@async` function depends on the results from a `NativeQuery` ran from its own `@PersistenceContext`.

The problem is that the native query inside the `@async` function is running before the first transaction has flushed, which means the entity has not yet been flushed to the database.

What is the best way to make sure the `@async` function only runs *after* completing the currently open transaction? I tried wrapping the `@async` function in it's own `@transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation, and also manually calling `em.flush()` inside the first transaction before calling the async method, but neither changed the outcome.

Here is a simplified version of my code (Edit- added some additional detail):

WebController

```
@Controller
class WebController {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    AsyncService service;

    @RequestMapping("/createObject")
    @Transactional
    @ResponseBody
    public Obj createObj(Obj obj){
        em.persist(obj);

        //Run the time consuming async task for the newly-persisted entity
        service.runAsyncMethod(obj.getId());

        return obj;
    }

}
```

AsyncService

```
@Service
@EnableAsync
class AsyncService {

     @PersistenceContext
     EntityManager em;

     @Async
     public void runMethod(Long itemId) {
         //Run native query
         Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select name from obj where id = :objId")
         query.setParameter("objId", itemId);


         List results = query.getResultsList()
         //`results` is empty
     }
}
```

Additionally: if I turn on `hibernate.show_sql` in my persistence config, the SQL statements printed *look* like they are in the correct order:

```
    Hibernate: insert into content (id, name) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: select name from obj where id = ?
```

Finally, if I wrap the `service.runAsyncMethod()` call in a `java.util.TimerTask` and schedule it for a 1 second delay, it *does* work as expected.

The asyncMethod is called from multiple different web endpoints in my application.

Is there a way (maybe via AOP?) to tell the async function to only run after the current transaction has flushed?

Comment: Without committing the data another transaction cannot see the data. If you want it to run after the other method then run it after the other method. Create a (non transactional) service that first calls the method to persist the stuff and next calls the other method.

Comment: You're right - that would probably be the best solution for the simplified example I provided. Unfortunately the async method is called from many different transactional @RequestMapping methods, which would require a big refactor to wrap them all. The data passed to the async method depends on which method is being called, so it would be tricky to just wrap it in a servlet filter.

Comment: Ehr? Servlet Filter? Where doest that come from? Also why does the async call have to change... You want to change the location where this is called in combination with what you have here. Apparently the question you asked isn't going to give you the answer you want/need due to the over simplification of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this if async method called after transaction commit (flush complete). This can be implemented by calling the async method in overridden afterCommit() of TransactionSynchronizationAdapter (abstract class provided by Spring) and register this TransactionSynchronizationAdapter object in TransactionSynchronizationManager (which helps transaction synchronization).

Ex:

```
@Controller
class WebController {
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;

   @Autowired
   AsyncService service;

   @Transactional
   public Obj createObj(Obj obj){
        em.persist(obj);

        // Call the Async method only after transaction commit.
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {

           // Override the afterCommit which need to be executed after transaction commit
           public void afterCommit() { 
              //Run the time consuming async task for the newly-persisted entity
              service.runAsyncMethod(obj.getId());
           }
         }

        return obj;
      }

    }
```